# Pandas multilevel index to and from sql

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, pandas

I have a multilevel column index group object that I am trying to send and retrieve from an SQlite database.  Pandas by default converts the index into a string that looks like a tuple (which is great), but the issue that I'm having is when the table is read back, the multilevel index is lost and I'm left with string tuples as column headers.

Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sqlite3

# Create a dataframe
data = {'Pets and Fruits'  : ["Apples", "Oranges", "Puppies", "Ducks"]*5,
        'C1'     : [1., 2., 3., 4.]*5,
        'C2'     : [1., 2., 3., 4.]*5,}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Groupby dataframe
df = df.groupby("Pets and Fruits").agg(['sum', 'mean'])

# Create a sqlite database
db = sqlite3.connect("Fruits and Pets.sqlite")

# Send the group to the database
df.to_sql(name="fruits_and_pets", con=db, if_exists='replace')

# Read back the table
df_read = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT * FROM fruits_and_pets''',con=db,index_col="Pets and Fruits")

print df
print df_read
```

Before going to database:

```
                   C1         C2     
                  sum mean   sum mean
Pets and Fruits                      
Apples            5.0  1.0   5.0  1.0
Ducks            20.0  4.0  20.0  4.0
Oranges          10.0  2.0  10.0  2.0
Puppies          15.0  3.0  15.0  3.0
```

Coming back form database:

```
                 ('C1', 'sum')  ('C1', 'mean')  ('C2', 'sum')  ('C2', 'mean')
Pets and Fruits                                                              
Apples                     5.0             1.0            5.0             1.0
Ducks                     20.0             4.0           20.0             4.0
Oranges                   10.0             2.0           10.0             2.0
Puppies                   15.0             3.0           15.0             3.0
```

I can use `df_read.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([eval(x) for x in df_read.columns])` to turn the dataframe back into a multilevel index, but I'm wondering if there is a better method or a built in that I'm missing?

Comment: I'd recommend to use `ast.literal_eval()` instead of `eval()` as it might be used for injections...

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sqlite3

# Create a dataframe
data = {'Pets and Fruits'  : ["Apples", "Oranges", "Puppies", "Ducks"]*5,
        'C1'     : [1., 2., 3., 4.]*5,
        'C2'     : [1., 2., 3., 4.]*5,}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Groupby dataframe
df = df.groupby("Pets and Fruits").agg(['sum', 'mean'])
df['Pets and Fruits'] = df.index.values
df = df.melt(id_vars='Pets and Fruits',var_name=['C','agg_type'])
# Create a sqlite database
db = sqlite3.connect("Fruits and Pets.sqlite")

# Send the group to the database
df.to_sql(name="fruits_and_pets", con=db, if_exists='replace',index=False)

# Read back the table
df_read = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT * FROM fruits_and_pets''',con=db,index_col=["C","agg_type"])#,index_col=["Pets and Fruits",])
df_read = df_read.pivot(columns='Pets and Fruits').T
df_read.index = df_read.index.droplevel(0)
print(df)
print(df_read)
```